# How to find all the invariant subspaces in relation to Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, invariant-subspace

> Let
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
> -1 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
> 0 & 0 & 3 & 1\\
> 0 & 0 & -1 & 1
> \end{bmatrix}\in M_4(\mathbb C)$$
> I need to find all the $A$-invariant subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^{4}$.

I proved a theorem that says: every subspace which is $J_{k}\left(\lambda\right) $ invariant when $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of A is of the form $Span\left(e_{i},\ldots,e_{k}\right)$, and I know how to find the Canonical Jordan form of A, but I don't understand how to use the theorem or if there is another way to find all the invariant subspaces of A.

Answer (score 1):

If $\ J=P^{-1}AP\ $ is the Jordan canonical form of an $\ n\times n\ $ matrix $\ A\ $, then
$$
Av=v\Leftrightarrow JP^{-1}v= P^{-1}v\,
$$
so $\ V\ $ is an invariant subspace of $\ A\ $ if and only if $\ P^{-1}V\ $ is an invariant subspace of $ J\ $.

Let
$$
J=\pmatrix{J_1&0&\dots&\dots&\dots&0\\
0&J_2&\dots&\dots&\dots&0\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
\vdots&&&J_i&&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\dots&\dots&\dots&J_k}\ ,
$$
where each $\ J_i\ $ is a Jordan block of size $\ s_i\ $ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\ \lambda_i\ $. If $\ e_{ij}\ $ is the $\ j^{\,\text{th}}\ $ column of the $\ s_i\times s_i\ $ identity matrix, then $\ \big(J_i-\lambda_iI\big)e_{i1}=0\ $ and $\ \big(J_i-\lambda_iI\big)e_{ir}=e_{i\,r-1}\ $ for $\ r=2,3,\dots,s_i\ $. The matrix $\ J_i\ $ therefore has $\ s_i+1\ $ distinct invariant subspaces—namely $\ \{0\}\ $ and
$$
  Span\left(\big\{e_{ij}\,\big|\,j=1,2,\dots,r\,\big\}\right)
$$
for $\ r=1,2,\dots,s_i\ $. Assume $\ \lambda_i\ne\lambda_j\ $ for $\ i\ne j\ $. The invariant subspaces of $\ J\ $ are then all subspaces of $\ \mathbb{C}^n\ $ of the form
$$
W_1\times W_2\times\dots\times W_k\  
$$
where each $\ W_i\ $ is an invariant subspace of $\ J_i\ $. There are thus $\ \prod_\limits{i=1}^k\big(s_i+1\big)\ $ distinct invariant subspaces of $\ J\ $, obtained by allowing each $\ W_i\ $ in the above Cartesian product to take on each of its $\ s_i+1\ $ possible values.

If $\ t_1=1\ $ and $\ t_i=1+\sum_\limits{j=1}^{i-1}s_j\ $ for $\ i=2,3,\dots,k\ $ and $\ \pi_{ir}\ $ is the $\ \big(t_i+r-1\big)^\text{th}\ $  column of the matrix $\ P\ $, then $\ \pi_{i1},\pi_{i2},\dots,\pi_{is_i}\ $ are the columns of $\ P\ $ corresponding to the Jordan block $\  J_i\ $. For those columns, we have $\ \big(A-\lambda_iI\big)\pi_{i1}=0\ $ and $\ \big(A-\lambda_iI\big)\pi_{ir}=\pi_{i\,r-1}\ $ for $\ r=2,3,\dots,s_i\ $, and for each invariant subspace of $\ J_i\ $ we get a corresponding invariant subspace $\ \{0\}\ $ or
$$
  Span\left(\big\{\pi_{ij}\,\big|\,j=1,2,\dots,r\,\big\}\right)
$$
of $\ A\ $.  The invariant subspaces of $\ A\ $ are all subspaces of $\ \mathbb{C}^n\ $ of the form
$$
V_1\oplus V_2\oplus\dots\oplus V_k
$$
where each $\ V_i\ $ is an invariant subspace of $\ A\ $ corresponding to the Jordan block $\ J_i\ $.

[Event Horizon's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4448378/how-to-find-all-the-invariant-subspaces-in-relation-to-matrix/4448426#4448426) has given the Jordan canonical form for your $\ A\ $, with three Jordan blocks of sizes $\ 1, 1\ $ and $\ 2\ $ and three of the columns of $\ P\ $:
$$
\pi_{11}=\pmatrix{i\\1\\0\\0},\ \pi_{21}=\pmatrix{-i\\1\\0\\0},\ \pi_{31}=\pmatrix{1/2\\1/2\\1\\-1}
$$
(where I have inverted the sign of the third column). The fourth column can be any solution, $\ v\ $, of the equation $\ \big(A-2I\big)v=\pi_{31}\ $.  I'll take it to be
$$
\pi_{32}=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}\\1\\1\\0}\ .
$$
Using the notation $\ \big\langle v_1,v_2,\dots, v_n\big\rangle\triangleq Span\big(v_1,v_2,\dots, v_n\big)\ $, we can list the twelve invariant subspaces of your matrix $\ A\ $ as
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{Dim }0&\{0\}\\
\text{Dim }1&\big\langle\pi_{11}\big\rangle,\ \big\langle\pi_{21}\big\rangle,\ \big\langle\pi_{31}\big\rangle\\
\text{Dim }2&\big\langle\pi_{11},\pi_{21}\big\rangle,\ \big\langle\pi_{11},\pi_{31}\big\rangle,\ \big\langle\pi_{21},\pi_{31}\big\rangle ,\ \big\langle\pi_{31},\pi_{32}\big\rangle\\
\text{Dim }3&\big\langle\pi_{11},\pi_{21},\pi_{31}\big\rangle,\ \big\langle\pi_{11},\pi_{31},\pi_{32}\big\rangle,\ \big\langle\pi_{21},\pi_{31},\pi_{32}\big\rangle\\
\text{Dim }4&\big\langle\pi_{11},\pi_{21},\pi_{31},\pi_{32}\big\rangle=\mathbb{C}^4\ .
\end{array}

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment:*

We know that: *a subspace $U$ is invariant under the matrix $A\in M_{n}(F)$ if, and only if, $$\forall u\in U:\quad Au\in U$$*
However,  as far as I have learned, finding them all is not always an easy task, but if the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, everything is usually easier.

Notice that, the characteristic polynomial for $A$ is given by
$$p_{A}(\lambda)=\lambda^{4}-6\lambda^{3}+14\lambda^{2}-16\lambda+8$$
The polynomial can be factorable over $\mathbb{C}$ but by hypothesis $A\in M_{4}(\mathbb{C})$ so no problem.

$$p_{A}(\lambda)=(\lambda-2)^{2}(\lambda-2\lambda+2)$$
Then the characteristic equation is given by
$$p_{A}(\lambda)=0\implies \lambda_{1}=2,\quad \lambda_{2}=1+i,\quad \lambda_{3}=1-i$$
With algebraic multiplicity $2,1,1$ to $2,1+i, 1-i$ respectively. We know $A$ is diagonalizable if, and only if, the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$ is the same which the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$ for each $i$.

However solving $(A-\lambda_{i}I)=\vec{0}$ for each eigenvalues we get

$$\lambda_{1}=2\longrightarrow v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}-1/2\\-1/2\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}\implies 2\not=1$$
$$\lambda_{2}=1+i\longrightarrow v_{2}=\begin{pmatrix} -i\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\implies 1=1$$
$$\lambda_{3}=1-i\longrightarrow v_{3}=\begin{pmatrix}i\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\implies 1=1$$
So $A$ is not diagonalizable since the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda_{1}=2$ is not the same of geometric multiplicity.

Hence in this problem you have to work step-by-step using the definition given above and your theorem also should be useful because give a characterisation for the invariant subspace with the canonical Jordan form $J=\begin{pmatrix} 1-i&0&0&0\\0&1+i&0&0\\0&0&2&1\\0&0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$ where $A=PJP^{-1}$ with $P$ be a invertible matrix.

By other hand,notice for example the subspaces $\{\vec{0}\}$ and $\mathbb{C}^{4}$ they're invariant subspaces. Indeed, $A\vec{0}=\vec{0}\in\{\vec{0}\}$ and $Au=u\in \mathbb{C}^{4}$ for all $u\in\mathbb{C}^{4}$. Now see in the columns span, rows span, etc.

If $M_{4}(\mathbb{C})$ is working over the field $\mathbb{C}$ so $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}\left(M_{4}(\mathbb{C})\right)=4^{2}$ and it should be useful.

Comment: thank you for the elaborated comment, can you explain how can i use the theorem? i couldn't understand how to use the theorem since its about the Jordan Blocks and not the Jordan matrix. what information do i get from using the theorem in regards to the Jordan matrix itself? also is there a way to find all the invariant subspaces without actually calculating the Jordan matrix?

Comment: @LielAzulay Well, I wrote "...your theorem should be useful..." I should know the proof of that theorem to see how it works. This problem, as I had mentioned, is not usually easy and must be done step by step, reviewing each dimension. My post was too long for a comment and of course doesn't fully answer your question. I am sure that in the forum there are much more experienced users than me in this field. For now the only thing that occurs to me is the hard way of doing everything step by step through the dimensions. No more ideas for now.